# new Date() returns a time of 8 PM on the heroku server even though I enter a time of 11:59 PM. How can I make it accurate?

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, reactjs

When I run my app locally, I get an accurate time of day from new Date() (The date is generated from a string, and time of day is manually entered as 11:59 PM on the server). When I push my app up to heroku, the time is always returned as 8 PM when it should be 11:59PM. Every time value is 4 hours behind what I should be returning from the database. I am not sure why or how this is happening. I am using these times in a chart, so before I draw the chart, I format the data like so:

```
formatDataForThisWeeksChart(salesData) {

    let dataRowsForChart = salesData.map(monthData => {
      //monthData[0] is the string value of each month of a year
      let newMonthData = [new Date(monthData[0]), monthData[1]];
      console.log(newMonthData);
      return newMonthData;
    });

    this.setState({
      dataRowsForChart
    }, () => {
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(this.drawThisWeeksRevenueChart);
    });
  }
```

Why would I be getting a time that's 4 hours behind? This is how I return the data from my API endpoint:

```
[new Date(currentYear, 0, 1, 23, 59), janRevenue]
```

You can see I have 23 and 59 entered as the values for hours and minutes. Those return as expected when I run this app locally. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Presumably you're European and east of Greenwich. 

https://coderwall.com/p/j9_e8a/set-timezone-for-your-heroku-app

Comment: If I am entering the time manually as 23, 59 --- does it still matter if what timezone I am in?

Comment: The timezone of the local environment running the code matter. And it seems like plenty of other people have had this problem on heroku.

http://iamnotmyself.com/2012/06/18/how-deep-a-simple-problem-can-get-moment-node-heroku-time-zones/

Comment: When you say "monthData[0] is the string value of each month of a year", what exactly do you mean? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds timezone related. Rather than `new Date(...)`, try the `Date.UTC(...)` function. See [the docs on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC).